# Setting "working directory" in visual studio property sheet, $(ProjectDir) or $(TargetDir), which is better?

Tags: visual-studio

The default value of *working directory* in visual studio property sheet is `$(ProjectDir)`. If we have some dependencies (e.g., config files or libs & dlls), we have to put them in the *working directory*.

Since the default `$(ProjectDir)` is different from the *output directory* (namely `$(TargetDir)`, folder where the EXE file resides), we have to copy the dependencies to the *output directory* if we run the EXE file by double clicking it.

So I'd like to change my *working directory* to `$(TargetDir)`, in case I have to copy my dependencies twice. The question is: Why is the **default** *working directory* set to `$(ProjectDir)` but not `$(TargetDir)`? Is there any good reason for visual studio to do so?

Comment: Because that's the way it has worked for the past 25 years.

Comment: @HansPassant, since I'm 23 years old, would you like to elaborate *why* it worked that way for so many years? ;-)

Comment: Hard to see why that matters.  Disk drives were very slow back then, nobody cared much for having to wait while files were getting copied before getting the debug session started.  Just change the setting to do it your way, that's why it is there.